# Why is one meeting time wrong

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, exchange

I have an Exchange account through work with many meetings.  They all show correctly on my PC and my phone (Nexus 6P)...  except for one.
It's a recurring meeting and it shows that it happens 1 hour before it actually does - only on my phone.
I even deleted the meeting and had the meeting owner resend the invitation.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Check time zones.

Comment: If Time zone was off, all of the meetings should be off by the same amount though, right?  Even so, time zone for device and for that account have been verified.